# Shrinkwrap addAsLibrary() add library to wrong path

Tags: jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I am currently writing some integration tests with Arquillian. Now I'm stuck at a strange problem:

I have a .war archive and want to add a .jar library to it. I do this with myWar.addAsLibrary(myJar). However, like this the myJar is then located at

```
myWar
 \_ WEB-INF/lib/WEB-INF/lib/myJar.jar
```

instead of

```
myWar
 \_ WEB-INF/lib/myJar.jar
```

I made a workaround that exports the jar to the file system and adds it like this:

```
myWar.addAsLibrary(new File("/home/metalhamster/myJar.jar"), 
                   new BasicPath("/WEB-INF/lib/myJar.jar"));
```

Has anyone an idea what the problem is? Is it maybe a bug of ShrinkWrap?

---

**EDIT:**

What I have tried:

```
// load original war
WebArchive myWar = ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(WebArchive.class, new File("../wgmdb-web/build/wgmdb-web.war"));

// extract jar from war
JavaArchive myJar = myWar.getAsType(JavaArchive.class, new BasicPath("/WEB-INF/lib/wgmdb-business.jar"));

/*
 * modify the jar
 */

// replace the jar with the modified version
myWar.delete(new BasicPath("/WEB-INF/lib/wgmdb-business.jar"));
myWar.addAsLibrary(myJar);
```

Workaround:

```
// export jar to file system
new ZipExporterImpl(myJar).exportTo(new File("/home/metalhamster/wgmdb/wgmdb-business.jar");

// load it again and add it to the war
war.addAsLibrary(new File("/home/metalhamster/wgmdb/wgmdb-business.jar"), 
                 new BasicPath("/WEB-INF/lib/wgmdb-business.jar"));
```

Cheers 
metalhamster

Comment: Could you share your actual ShrinkWrap code example?

Comment: Agree, this is not expected behavior. Would you report a issue at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SHRINKWRAP ?  A better workaround would be war.add(myJar, ArchivePaths.create("/"), ZipExporter.class) to avoid the export to filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ShrinkWrap is doing what you are asking: add `/WEB-INF/lib/myJar.jar` to the lib directory.

To fix this remove the `/WEB-INF/lib/`:

```
myWar.addAsLibrary(new File("/home/metalhamster/myJar.jar"), 
                   new BasicPath("myJar.jar"));
```